# What were all the known kingsguard before and during the show and books?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I've seen some video's about many kingsguards and their deeds, who are they all? side-question: how did they leave their service?

Comment: A Kingsguard doesn't leave service unless he dies or is sent to the Wall. Deserting is also considered the end of service although if you are caught, you'll die for breaking your oath. Joffrey's dismissal of Selmy on account of advanced age was a break from tradition and generally accepted as a foolish thing to do. For list, see the link Mike provided.

Answer (score 3):

There are around a hundred known members of the Kingsguard in the books, and I’m not going to copy the entire list. See it [here](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kingsguard#Historical_Members).

Until Joffrey dismisses Barristan Selmy from the Kingsguard, the only way to leave it is to die.